# Automated LAN Matchmaking

Tags: game-mechanics, peer-to-peer, matchmaking

I'm looking to build an automated LAN matchmaking system for games and wondering if/how it would differ from the online applications (like FaceIt, ESEA) that serve a similar function. Ideally, a user would first select the game they wanted to play (PUBG, LoL, etc) then be paired up with others on the LAN who are playing the same game. Is that possible?

Comment: When you're tempted to ask "Is X possible?" try to unpack what's making you ask. Who would forbid it? What technological obstacle would prevent it? What law of physics would it breach? If you don't have an answer to any of those, then your question might not be about abstract possibility, but more practical: "HOW do I do it?" So - walk us through your understanding of the problem so far, what steps you think your game needs to perform, which ones you understand or have successfully implemented thus far, and where you're stuck. Then we can target our answers to help you with that specific need.

Comment: Thanks, Gregory. Completely get what you're saying. Admittedly, I'm very green when it comes to the development portion of my challenge/objective, so my initial goal is to figure out where the primary hurdles will come into play. I believe the answer from Josh below gets to the key issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @Stephen Welcome to GDSE. Please consider [voting on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (and optionally accepting one) in response to how helpful (or not) you find them to be. Doing so helps others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by having your matchmaking launcher/client use UDP broadcast to advertise their existing on the network. Clients can broadcast information about themselves (such who they are and what their actual LAN address is) while the client is open, and in turn receive those broadcasts from others. This allows each client to build up a view of other clients on the network.

From there you can directly negotiate connections to send more heavyweight information (such as who is playing what).

The main hurdle you'll likely run into is actually interfacing in any clean fashion with the actual games. Your client may be able to tell what the user is playing by monitoring the active process list on the machine (looking for "PUBG.exe" or whatever), but achieving any kind of seamless join from your client program *directly* will be a challenge. Unless a game exposes some kind API for you to query against (which is extremely unusual), you can't tell if somebody playing a game is actually in a lobby or joinable state or even present at the machine.

Building any kind of seamless join from your client program is thus going to involve a lot of per-game hacking and reverse-engineering, and may be impossible for many games.

If all you're trying to do is give users an idea of who is playing what now, and let them handle negotiating the join themselves, this is fairly doable.